# Already Used Theme.AppCompat decendant But still Error

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-theme, android-styles

I have an activity that uses a custom theme from:

[image: Custom theme style that uses the theme.appcompat]

As you can see, the custom theme is already a descendant of the theme.appcompat.

This is how i used it on my actvitiy from manifest file:
[image: Manifest Implementation of activity]

My Acitivity already extends the AppCompatActivity but I still get the must use Theme.Appcompat or its decendants error when i run my program. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What's about the style in values-v21?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: So I think Do this]

So I think Do this go to AppTheme and change it

Answer (score 0):

You have to change in style.xml

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```